# Seaborn boxplot and regplot shifted

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

When I set the boxplot and regplot in one chart, I get a shifted regression chart along the x-axis. When I plot it separately, everything is fine. How to fix it?

```py
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.boxplot(x="size", y="tip", data=tips)
sns.regplot(x="size", y="tip", data=tips, scatter=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Package versions:
'seaborn', '0.10.0'
'matplotlib', '3.2.1'

Python: 3.7.7

Comment: The problem is with seaborn 0.10.0 and 0.9.1 (not sure exactly what the cause is). Your code works in version 0.9.0

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I do need to point out that kyrex's answer is problematic. The regression line and boxplot are likely still misaligned. I would confirm your regression line is the same with the truncate method and plotted alone. I suspect they will be shifted.

Answer (score -1):

Calling on other users to post a better solution!!

This answer is outdated and must not be followed. The solution results in a shifted regression as J-81 and ddkk have pointed out.

I too have this problem:
[This is the result when running the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZJ5f.png)

This issue is also called out on another post: [Seaborn : linear regression on top of a boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51825223/seaborn-linear-regression-on-top-of-a-boxplot)

Package versions:
'seaborn', '0.10.1'
'matplotlib', '3.1.3'

Python: 3.7.4

My solution around this is to use the `truncate` parameter under `seaborn.regplot`. Here is my code:

```
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.boxplot(x="size", y="tip", data=tips)
sns.regplot(x="size", y="tip", data=tips, scatter=False, truncate=False)
plt.show()
```

This is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNq4b.png).

Comment: as pointed out by @J-81 above and in line with the regplot()-documentation (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html#seaborn.regplot), this will not correct the shift but extend the linear regression. I suggest you edit or delete the answer.

Comment: Editing this answer would mean getting and posting the correct solution right? Seems the posts I linked are not updated as well. I may try Arkadiusz's code in updated libraries now.

Comment: People will still find this post when looking for solutions to their problem. Your answer suggests but unfortunately doesn't provide a solution to the question of aligning plot and regression. Worse, it results in a wrong representation of data by continuing the shifted regression. You could put that as a disclaimer or delete the post altogether as, in my opinion, it can do more harm than help.